# How to include config.properties like file in c# console application so that i can modify it application should take the values?

Tags: c#-4.0, properties, config

I am working on a C# console application.
I want to include some properties file which has name value sort pf pairs which i can use during runtime and can be editable like config.properties in java
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just [add an App.config file to the project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx)

Then setup your config file to hold the property values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Property1" value="value1"/>
    <add key="Property2" value="value2"/>
    <add key="Property3" value="value3"/>
  </appSettings>    </configuration>
```

After that, you will need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the .NET `System.Configuration` assembly (if you don't already have it referenced) in the Solution Explorer for your project.

Then you can do something like this

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace YourAppNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string property1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Property1"];
            string property2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Property2"];
            string property3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Property3"];

            Console.WriteLine(property1);
            Console.WriteLine(property2);
            Console.WriteLine(property3);
        }
    }
}
```